# Storing answers and questions in database android studio

Tags: sqlite, android-studio

So im planning make an app that features a multiple choice(about factoring) kind of a mini game. Just wondering if it is possible to store questions and answers in a database so that i can randomize the order of it appearing? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve it but depends on your question answer size and count.

Because if you are using SQLite then it has limit to store data's and anyone can play with your data as its stored in user mobile memory.

I would suggest you to go with some higher DB with server side response so fetch everything fetch from server using API call so it would benefit you for long time.